# V4L2 - Device does not trigger epoll event

Tags: c, linux, v4l2

I have a camera where I only want to pick up images under certain conditions.
What I do is I register it with epoll with flags `0` which means it never gets reported by epoll_wait.
I have a second file descriptor which is an event. When this event gets triggered it is supposed to arm the camera file descriptor device by setting `EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT`.
The issue is that the camera descriptor doesn't always get triggered.
If I register it normally triggering doesn't happen:

```
addFD(epollFD, cameraFD, 0)
```

If I instead register it with `EPOLLIN` and than remove it before streaming capabilities of the camera are turned on (so no incoming event can happen), it works as expected:

```
addFD(epollFD, cameraFD, EPOLLIN);
modFD(epollFD, cameraFD, 0);
```

Building a minimal code example is quit hard. Does anyone know if this is a bug? and where should I report something like this? at v4l2? or is this an epoll bug? How could I figure something like this out?

Fullcode:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>

void onFailure(int error, char const* msg) {
    if (error == -1) {
        perror(msg);
        abort();
    }
}

void addFD(int epollFD, int eventFD, int flags) {
    struct epoll_event event;
    event.events  = flags;
    event.data.fd = eventFD;
    onFailure(epoll_ctl(epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, eventFD, &event), "failed to add eventFD");
}

void modFD(int epollFD, int eventFD, int flags) {
    struct epoll_event event;
    event.events = flags;
    event.data.fd = eventFD;
    onFailure(epoll_ctl(epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, eventFD, &event), "cannot call mod epoll");
}


void setCameraFormat(int cameraFD, int width, int height) {
    struct v4l2_format fmt;
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    fmt.fmt.pix.width       = width;
    fmt.fmt.pix.height      = height;
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
    fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_ANY;
    onFailure(ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt), "failed to set resolution");
}

void queueImage(int cameraFD, int idx) {
        struct v4l2_buffer buffer;

        buffer.type   = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buffer.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        buffer.index  = idx;

        onFailure(ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buffer), "cannot queue image buffer");
}

int dequeueImage(int cameraFD) {
    struct v4l2_buffer buffer;

    buffer.type   = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    buffer.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

    if (-1 == ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buffer)) {
        switch (errno) {
            case EAGAIN:
                return -1;
            case ENODEV:
                perror("no device");
                abort();
            default:
                perror("error");
                abort();
        }
    }
    return buffer.index;
}


void* setCameraBuffer(int cameraFD) {
    // set buffers
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;
    req.count  = 1;
    req.type   = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    onFailure(ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req), "failed to set buffers");
    void* buffer = 0;

    struct v4l2_buffer buf;

    buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    buf.index = 0;

    onFailure(ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf), "failed setting VIDIOC_QUERYBUF");
    buffer = mmap(0, buf.length
                , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
                , MAP_SHARED
                , cameraFD
                , buf.m.offset);
    if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("error memory mapping failed");
        abort();
    }
    queueImage(cameraFD, 0);
    return buffer;
}

void startCapturing(int cameraFD) {
    enum v4l2_buf_type type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    onFailure(ioctl(cameraFD, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type), "error starting video stream");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int epollFD  = epoll_create1(0);
    int cameraFD = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    int moduleFD = eventfd(0, EFD_NONBLOCK);

    setCameraFormat(cameraFD, 640, 480);
    void* buffer = setCameraBuffer(cameraFD);

    // register cameraFD
    #if 0 // change to 0 and it will work, but why?
        addFD(epollFD, cameraFD, 0);
    #else
        addFD(epollFD, cameraFD, EPOLLIN);
        modFD(epollFD, cameraFD, 0);
    #endif

    addFD(epollFD, moduleFD, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);
    startCapturing(cameraFD);

    onFailure(eventfd_write(moduleFD, 1), "could not write event");


    while(1) {
        printf("loop\n");
        struct epoll_event queue[5];
        int nums = epoll_wait(epollFD, queue, 5, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < nums; ++i) {
            if (queue[i].data.fd == cameraFD) {
                int img = dequeueImage(cameraFD);
                printf("camera\n");
                queueImage(cameraFD, img);
                onFailure(eventfd_write(moduleFD, 1), "could not write event");
            } else if (queue[i].data.fd == moduleFD) {
                printf("trampoline\n");
                modFD(epollFD, cameraFD, EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>`  Why is this header file being included twice?

Comment: when setting .events and/or width and/or height, need to pay attention to the values being unsigned int 32,  so the values being set into those fields should also be unsigned int 32, not `int`